# Организация Factory method

Tags: java, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня возникла необходимость написать объекты, связанные посредником

Структура проекта выглядит сейчас примерно так:

**Интерфейс посредника**

```
public interface ForkMediator {
void appendFork(ForkedObject forkedObject); //добавление объекта к посреднику
ForkedObject[] getForkData(ForkedObject forkedObject); //вернуть все объекты связанные с forkedObject
}
```

**Интерфейс объектов соединяемых посредником**

```
public interface ForkedObject{
double getPositive();
double getNegative();
double getJPositive();
double getJNegative();
void Run();
```

}

Конечному пользователю я не хочу предоставлять знание о том, что ForkedObject используют ForkMediator. ForkMediator имеет разную логику для различного количества добавленных к нему ForkedObject. Т.е если ForkMediator следит за 2 объектами, то его логика принципиально отличается от логики ForkMediator, который следит за 3 объектами

Я хочу предоставить пользователю интерфейс ForkObjectsFactory и некоторый набор классов конкретных фабрик:
TwoForkObjects (создает 2 объекта и посредника для них), ThreeForkObjects(создает три объекта и посредника для них). В целом количество фабрик будет не очень большим.

*Проблема в следующем*: Все конкретные ForkObject имеют 2 обязательных параметра, мне в голову приходит только такая реализация фабрики для создания этих объектов

**Интерфейс фабрики**

```
public interface ForkFactory {
     ForkedObject[] getObjects();
}
```

**Конкретный класс фабрики возвращающей массив из 2 ForkedObject связанных посредником**

```
public class TwoForkFactory implements ForkFactory {

    private Fork[] forks=new Fork[2];

    public TwoForkFactory(double field1Fork1, double field2Fork1,double field1Fork2, double field2Fork2){
        ForkMediator twoForkMediator=new TwoForkMediator();
        forks[0]=new Fork(field1Fork1, field2Fork1, twoForkMediator);
        forks[1]=new Fork(field1Fork2, field2Fork2, twoForkMediator);
    }

    @Override
    public ForkedObject[] getObjects() {
        return forkPipelines;
    }
```

**Вызов в пользовательском коде**

```
ForkFactory factory= new TwoForkFactory (1.0, 2.0, 1.1, 2.5);
ForkedObject[] forkObjects=factory.getObjects();
forkObjects[0].Run(); //в этом методе посредник передает данные между forkObjects
```

*Может быть есть более аккуратное решение, чтобы не передавать в конструктор TwoForkFactory 4 параметра (а для ThreeForkFactory их уже станет 6)?*

Comment: вы прислали какую-то ерунду. public TwoForkFactory(double FieldOneFork1, double FieldTwoFork2, double FieldOneFork2, double FieldTwoFork2) - что это? сколько у вас параметров в методе? у вас три параметра называются одинаково, так не может быть. количество этих параметров связано с тем, какую имплементацию ForkFactory нужно использовать? напишите пример еще одной имплементации для понимания логики. и исправьте то, что есть (одинаковые параметры в методе), ведь для того, чтобы что-то посоветовать, нужно понять логику работы. а еще переменные именуются с маленькой буквы!!! это очень важно

Comment: Извиняюсь, не внимательно посмотрел сигнатура конструктора конечно другая . public TwoForkFactory(double fieldOneFork1, double fieldTwoFork1, double fieldOneFork2, double fieldTwoFork2) . Имплементируем метод ForkedObject[] getObjects() он вернет массив из ForkedObject[] в для TwoForkFactory его размер будет ForkedObject[2]. Вопрос исправил, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: хорошо, теперь давайте дальше. TwoForkFactory создает 2 экземпляра класса Fork и отправляет их в массив. это происходит в конструкторе. массив объектов Fork  приватный. геттеров и сеттеров нет, доступа к нему нет, а переопределенный метод возвращает уже ForkedObject. что это за магия и как это связано? зачем вообще массив Fork  , ведь он никак на используется.

Comment: Я вас понял. Fork это класс имплементирующий ForkedObject. При запуске метода Run(), объявленного в ForkedObject и перегруженного в Fork происходят вычисления, для которых нужно участие посредника. Fork имплементирует ForkedObject и эта магия называется полиморфизм подтипов. Задача TwoForkFactory вернуть массив из двух объектов типа Fork, чтобы он мог сделать что то типа forkObjects[0].Run()  и при вызове этого метода обратиться к посреднику, чтобы получить данные из forkObjects[1].

Comment: Можно например представить дорогу которая расходится на 2.Если одна из них перекрыта все машины едут по другой и ее нельзя перекрывать. Чтобы одна из дорог узнала о том, что другая перекрыта, используется посредник ForkMediator. Проблема в том, что логика посредника для другого числа дорог другая. Кроме того каждой дороге при ее создании надо задать ряд параметров, которые и передаются в конструктор TwoForkFactory. В общем вопрос по сути в том, есть ли какое то решение, чтобы Factory создавало объекты с уже установленными свойствами, а не как у GoF просто вернули объект базового класса и все.

Answer (score 0):

По описанию это выглядит странно. Если вы сможете выложить код со всеми указанными классами, я думаю, найдется решение на много проще описанного. Кроме того, GoF - это не готовые решения и тем более не ответ на все вопросы. Адаптировать GoF под текущую задачу нужно самому. Зачастую необходимо скручивать гибрид из нескольких паттернов. 
В данном случае вам нужен фабричный метод, который создает медиаторы. Канонически это отдельные классы (я имею в виду классы для реализации самого фабричного метода). Практически так уже никто не пишет. Для реализации фабричного метода используют статический метод в классе-родителе (интерфейсе), возвращающий переменную типа самого себя. Посмотрите в джаве на лист или сет, тем есть метод of() или в спринге Page.of(). никаких дополнительных классов. Что касается логики инициализации и определения , что именно создавать зависит только от вас. Посему то, что у вас называется фабрики, вообще не нужны. я сделал ForkMediator  абстрактным классом просто для того, чтобы реализовать приватный метод. инициализирующий массивы. вы можете вывести интерфейс. пеоскольку я не понял логики преобразования массива Fork в ForkedObject, я возвращаю вам массив Fork. Дальше все просто. Привожу класс ForkMediator  и клиентский код.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ForkMediator {

    public static Fork[] of(double ... args){
        switch(args.length/2){
            case 2: return createFork(new TwoForkMediator(), args);
        }
    }

    private Fork[] createFork (ForkMediator forkMediator, double ... args){
        final List<Fork> forks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i+=2) 
            forks.add(new Fork(args[i-1], args[i], forkMediator));
        return forks.toArray(new Fork[forks.size()]);
    }

    abstract void appendFork(ForkedObject forkedObject); //добавление объекта к посреднику

    abstract ForkedObject[] getForkData(ForkedObject forkedObject); //вернуть все объекты связанные с forkedObject
}

//вызов из клиента
Fork[] result = ForkMediator.of(1.0, 2.0, 1.1, 2.5);
```

опять же, если покажете весь код (можете на гите), то думаю, что решение будет другое